# Why assign value to string before comparing, when default is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why I always need to assign a value to string variable, before actually using it to compare.
For ex:
Some input - obj

```
        string temp;
        if (obj== null)
        {
            temp = "OK";
        }
        string final = temp;
```

I get compile time error - something like - cant use unassigned variable 'temp'. But string variable has default value as 'null', which I want to use. So why this is not allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when default is null

The default is **not** null (or anything else) for a local variable. It's just unassigned.

You are probably thinking about a string field (a variable at the class level). That would be `null` :

```
private string temp;

private void M()
{
   if (obj== null)
   {
       temp = "OK";
   }
   string final = temp;  // default tnull
}
```

But inside a method, just initialize with the value you need:

```
string temp = null;
```

Comment: Btw, a quick technical note. Because C# compiles to IL, and method-level IL is stack-based, variables technically do not exist unless they have been assigned.
While the debugger might tell you that an unassigned variable equals `0` or something, in most cases, this is just a courtesy. It will only be created later.

Comment: @GregRoss - and when it is created I believe it is `default(T)` , `null` in this case. But neither is observable to a C# programmer.

Comment: Not exactly. In IL, a variable cannot be declared without having an explicit value to which it can be assigned. In order to assign a variable to `default(T)` (or `null`), you would need to first retrieve this value using an explicit command, and only then allocate it. In practice, IL generated from C# never does this. While you might think you declared a variable, the IL usually doesn't declare it until it has a definite value to assign.

Answer (score 2):

Then assing null as default for your local variable:

```
string temp = null;
```

It's just a compiler hint that you might have forgotten to assign a value. By explicitely assigning null you're telling the compiler that you've  thought about it.

C# Language specification v. 4.0 section 1.6.6.2 "Method body and local variables" states the following:

> A method body can declare variables that are specific to the invocation of the method. Such variables are called local variables.
>   ...
>   C# requires a local variable to be **definitely assigned** before its value can be obtained.